# How to place an image on the bottom left of a sidebar?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

My CSS skills are not the best, but I do know some basics. I am trying to put this image of my logo of my personal brand on the bottom left of the side navigation bar but I am having trouble on how to do this effectively. I want to do it in a way, that the navigation bar is not widened by the image placed there, currently, as it stands, the side navigation becomes more wide as the image tag placed there.

[image]

This is my React code for the side navigation

```
const Sidebar = () => {
    return (
        <div className="sidebar">
            <div className="sideBarWrapper">
                <div className="sideBarMenu">
                    <h1 className="sideBarTitle">Dashboard</h1>
                        <ul className="sideBarList">
                            <li className="sideBarListItem">
                                <Home  className="sideBarIcon"/>
                                Home
                            </li>

                            <li className="sideBarListItem">
                            <Icon 
                            icon="mdi:currency-btc" 
                            className="sideBarIcon"
                            />
                                Cryptocurrency
                            </li>

                            <li className="sideBarListItem">
                            <Icon 
                            icon="whh:stocks" 
                            
                            className="sideBarIcon"
                            />
                                Stocks
                            </li>

                            <li className="sideBarListItem">
                                <Visibility  className="sideBarIcon"/>
                                Watchlist
                            </li>

                            <img className="img" src={Logo}/>
                        </ul>
                        
                </div>
                
            </div>   
        </div>
    )
}

export default Sidebar
```

And this is the CSS for the side navigation

```
.sidebar{
    flex: 1;
    height:  calc(100vh - 50px);
    background-color: goldenrod;
    position: sticky;
    top: 50px;
}

.sideBarWrapper{
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #555;
}

.sideBarMenu{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.sideBarTitle{
    font-size: 15px;
    color: black;
}

.sideBarList{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px;
}

.sideBarListItem{
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.sideBarListItem.active, .sideBarListItem:hover{
    background-color: whitesmoke
}

.sideBarIcon{
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-size: 50px !important;
}

.img{
   height: 300px;
   margin-right: 5px;
   bottom: 70px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing `position: absolute;` on the logo. Adding this will both (a) allow the logo to attach to the bottom of its nearest positioned ancestor (`.sideBarWrapper`), and (b) cause it to have no effect on the layout of its ancestors.

```css
.sidebar {
    background-color: goldenrod;
    height: 500px;
    width: 300px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.sideBarWrapper {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #555;
}

.sideBarMenu{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.sideBarTitle{
    font-size: 15px;
    color: black;
}

.sideBarList{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px;
}

.sideBarListItem{
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.sideBarListItem.active, .sideBarListItem:hover{
    background-color: whitesmoke
}

.sideBarIcon{
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-size: 50px !important;
}

.logo {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 70px;
    width: 120px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="sideBarWrapper">
        <div class="sideBarMenu">
            <h1 class="sideBarTitle">Dashboard</h1>
            <ul class="sideBarList">
                <li class="sideBarListItem">
                    Home
                </li>
                <li class="sideBarListItem">
                    Cryptocurrency
                </li>
                <li class="sideBarListItem">
                    Stocks
                </li>
                <li class="sideBarListItem">
                    Watchlist
                </li>
                <img class="logo" src='data:image/svg+xml;base64,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'>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>
```